# What's the origin of the Panamanian word "biñuelo"? Is it merely a corruption of "buñuelo"?

Tags: etimología, definiciones, diferencias-regionales, comida, panamá

I was in Panama about five years ago and there was a common deep fried street food called "biñuelo".

Of course there's a regular Spanish word "buñuelo" which means fritter.

So is "biñuelo" just the Panamanian regionalism for "buñuelo" or do they have both words and use them for slightly different things? It's common enough in Panama to see that it's not just a rare misspelling or mistake.

Or could "biñuelo" involve some kind of wordplay or have a totally different origin to "buñuelo" and just be similar by coincidence?

**Where does "biñuelo" come from and how does it relate to "buñuelo"?**

(It's not in the DRAE or other dictionaries I've checked but it's easy to find via Google, especially in the plural.)

Comment: I've been collecting unusual Spanish words in my travels for years. Now I have an excuse to dredge through some of them at last (-:

Comment: There's a Facebook [page](http://es-es.facebook.com/pages/Se%C3%B1oras-que-dicen-bi%C3%B1uelos-en-lugar-de-bu%C3%B1uelos/306108758510) for "Señoras que dicen "biñuelos" en lugar de buñuelos..."  The one post suggests the word is ["valenciano"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valencian) as opposed to "castellano".   I'm not sure what, if anything, we can learn from that.

Comment: @JonEricson, we can learn not to trust things people post on Facebook ;) In valencià it's *bunyol*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Biñuelo* is an Extremaduran<sup>1 2 3 4</sup> variant<sup>5 6</sup> of the word *buñuelo*:

> **U:** En el habla rústica se sustituye por *e:* *m**e**rmuración, m**e**rmurar,* y también por *i:* *b**i**ñuelo.*
>
> - [*Apuntes lingüísticos de Extremadura*](http://www.dip-badajoz.es/cultura/ceex/reex_digital/reex_X/1936/T.%20X%20n.%202%201936%20mayo-ag/RV09822.pdf)

Though not in the DLE, it appears in two older dictionaries:

> **BIÑUELO.** m. *Amer.C.* BUÑUELO. (CUERVO)
>
> - 1895 ZEROLO

> **Biñuelo.** m. *Amer.* En Colombia, buñuelo.
>
> - 1918 RODRÍGUEZ NAVAS

Its prevalence in Colombian (and Panamanian) Spanish is readily explained by the fact that many of the early colonisers of Colombia were of Extremaduran (and Andalusian) origin.<sup>7</sup>

---

**Notes:**

1. [*El español de América*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6pZE8TeU_HMC&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=%22bi%C3%B1uelo%22) (p.183)
2. [*REVISTA DE ESTUDIOS EXTREMEÑOS*](http://www.geolectos.com/cumbres.pdf)
3. [*Diccionario de palabras de mi infancia (Calamonte, años 50 y 60)*](https://en.calameo.com/books/004677820e7861bbcaeaa) (p.34)
4. [*Diccionario de Extremadura: Palabras usadas en Extremadura*](https://diccionariodeextremadura.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/b/)
5. > **IX. VOCES CORROMPIDAS.** e. Por cambio de vocales, en virtud de asimilación y simpatía: *bracelete, chiminea, infriar, chocozuela, culumpio, tutuma, fundillo, tubillo, tulundrón, añidir, **biñuelo**, ...*
   >
   > - [*Diccionario abreviado de galicismos, provincialismos y correcciones de lenguaje*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bUSTszy2cCgC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22bi%C3%B1uelo%22)
6. > En el vocalismo destaca sobre todo la fuerte tendencia a la supresión
   > vocálica ... y a la constante inestabilidad del vocalismo átono (... «biñuelo», 'buñuelo').
   >
   > - [*Dialectología y folclore en Extremadura en el tránsito del siglo XIX al XX*](http://nuestramusica.unex.es/nuestra_musica/bibliografia/habla4.pdf) (p.820)
7. [*La América española. El apasionamiento escenográfico, 1730–1810*](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610210625/http://aplicaciones.virtual.unal.edu.co/blogs/hacolombia/category/cap-ii/3-la-america-espanola-1730-1810/) (1990)

Answer (score 4):

It's just a deformation (pretty common in the jargon of Caribbean countries).

Comment: Is the change from "u" to "i" particularly common? Stack Exchange likes well fleshed out answers! (-:

Comment: Actually isn't that common (at least not for what I know).

Comment: @hippietrail I searched Google Panamá and I always got back recipes for fritters. I also found a Peruvian blog with pictures of `Biñuelos Arequipeños con miel` (looked yummy). Colombians say that someone is a `buñuelo` when that person is really bad at performing some task. `Soy un buñuelo para el fútbol` (I am a really lousy soccer player).

Comment: @Icarus, I'm from colombia. We don't use that al least not within the urban territories. It's used more to denote someone fat

Comment: @RandolRincón-Fadul: I disagree with your claim that is not used to refer to someone very inexperienced "or at least not in the urban territories". It's quite the opposite: It's more common its use to denote inexperience than someone being fat. A quick Google search for "buñuelo colombianismo", for example, will retrieve a bunch of links showing that "buñuelo" is the equivalent of principiante, novato, neófito, bisoño, inexperto, etc. See this Wikipedia article of colombianismos: http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Colombianismos